# web api tracing, library versions

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, nuget-package

My original problem was that I didn't get any xml response - only json - after changed to use XmlSerializer:

```
var xml = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter;
xml.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

so I wanted to install web api tracer as described: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/tracing-in-aspnet-web-api

after installing the tracing package and updating webhost I got the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference.

and here I'm, I could not resolve the problem and I'm not sure I understand it.

I'm coming from the java word where I used maven and it helped me to resolve dependencies, I could check pom.xml files, etc.

I guess the package manager works in a similar way, somehow dependencies are defined, but in my case I could not find anything in the logs or anywhere else which relates to System.Web.Http package.

I realized that I even cannot find the relevant web api package, and find out which version I'm using.

So could you please help me to clarify things from the very beginning,
- how can I find out which web api version I'm using, 
- where is the reference defined to this web api library
- how can I find out which web api version is required by the tracing package
- where is the reference to the System.Web.Http package?

I hope this will be enough to fix my problem.

thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web Api returns JSON or XML by default. It depends of how the consumer request the service. For instance, if you use jquery ajax request, you can indicate dataType: xml

Regarding the references, if you used Nuget, there's a file packages.config in your project that indicates the packages and versions installed. I guess it is similar to Maven.

Otherwise, you can always have a look to References in your Solution Explorer window and check the version of the library referenced.

By the way, to add System.Web.Http library (is part of the framework) go to References and Add new reference. Search for System.Web.Http in Framework section and add it to the project.

If you need more details let me know.

Comment: Web APi returns XML only if it can serialize all the objects. If not it falls back to the json serializer. When I configured to use XmlSerializer instead of DataContractSerializer it stopped returning xml anymore. That's why I wanted to install the tracer.

thanks for the hint about packages.config! 

I'll try it again and let you know the results.